# Comparing the dates and highlighting the result

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am comparing two Dates in columns D and E of My worksheet.

Column D contains the source Date and column E contains the Start date.

I have 4 cases to compare the date.

Case 1. If the sorce date is < 2 weeks of start date, then print Project on time.

case 2: if the source date is > 4 weeks of start date , then print Project delay.

case 3: if the source date is between 2 to 4 weeks of start date, then print Project is remaning.

I have derived the code for the above cases, Now

Case 4: not everytime the column E is filled with date, they are empty sometimes.

So, How would i add a null Statement here. I tried adding an null Statement, but it failed.

Below is the code.

```
Sub dateCompare()

zLastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To zLastRow

    zWeeks = (Cells(r, "E") - Cells(r, "D")) / 7
    Select Case zWeeks
        Case Is > 4
            zcolour = vbRed
            Ztext = "Project Delayed " & Int(zWeeks) & " weeks"
        Case 2 To 4
            zcolour = vbYellow
            Ztext = "Project Remaining"
        Case Is < 2
            zcolour = vbGreen
            Ztext = "Project On-Time"
        Case Else
            zcolour = xlNone
            Ztext = " Check Status"
    End Select

    Cells(r, "F").Interior.Color = zcolour
    Cells(r, "F") = Ztext            
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calculating `zWeeks` check the column "E" is not empty, with `If Len(Trim(Cells(r, "E"))) = 0 Then`. Afterwards, use your `Select Case`.

Also, you can use `DateDiff` function, with the first parameter being `"ww"` (weeks), to calculate directly the difference in weeks between the dats in column "E" amd column "D".

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub dateCompare()

Dim r As Long, zLastRow As Long
Dim zWeeks As Double, zcolour As Long
Dim Ztext  As String

zLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To zLastRow
    If Len(Trim(Cells(r, "E"))) = 0 Then ' column "E" is empty
        ' do something....
    Else ' column "E" is not empty
        zWeeks = DateDiff("ww", Cells(r, "D"), Cells(r, "E"))

        Select Case zWeeks
            Case Is > 4
                zcolour = vbRed
                Ztext = "Project Delayed " & Int(zWeeks) & " weeks"
            Case 2 To 4
                zcolour = vbYellow
                Ztext = "Project Remaining"
            Case Is < 2
                zcolour = vbGreen
                Ztext = "Project On-Time"
            Case Else
                zcolour = xlNone
                Ztext = " Check Status"
        End Select

        Cells(r, "F").Interior.Color = zcolour
        Cells(r, "F") = Ztext
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: With respect to that case, I would like to add a case, If column A and B is present and Column D is present, But there is no date in column E , it should print remaning. How would i do this ? sorry that i am adding this requirement really late.

Comment: @Mikz can you post a new question with that request, otherwise posts here will never be closed. Don't worry, other users (and me) will jump to answer

Comment: @ shai Rado, I already posted as new request under the Name Macros for comparing dates and ID  and highlighting them . but that answer was not satisfying.